# Kotlin - Assign value to variable or break and return function

Tags: kotlin

I would like to assign new value to my variable but if it is null I would like to break the flow, print out some logs and then call to return.

My variable's type is Image and it cannot be null.

Below is my solution.

Basic code I started:

```
val img = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: return
```

Code I finally created:

```
val img : Image = (reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: (Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!").also { return })) as Image
```

1. Is it the best way to do it?
2. Is it possible to create extension for that?

Comment: If you need the cast, something fishy must be going on here. But it looks correct at first glance, so I wonder if you actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the compiler is not smart enough to deal with `also` here but if you used `let` it would work without the cast:

```kotlin
val img : Image = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!").let { return }
```

This is because the type of `Log.d(...)` is `Unit`, so the type of `Log.d(...).also { ... }` is also `Unit` *in general*. The compiler doesn't see that the non-local return in this specific case will prevent the whole expression `Log.d(...).also { ... }` from resulting in a value (in practice it should have the type `Nothing`, but the compiler doesn't see it and still gives it the type `Unit`).

`let`, on the contrary, returns the value of the lambda expression, which in this case is really of type `Nothing` and therefore is correctly understood by the compiler.

Another option would be to reverse your null-handling section:

```kotlin
val img = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: return Unit.also { Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!!") }
```

> Is it the best way to do it?

In this form, I'm not convinced even by my own versions, which are probably not the most maintainable way of doing it. I would personally favor a plain `if` statement here for the log and `return`. The smart casting of Kotlin with flow typing will allow you to use your `img` variable with type `Image` after the check, even though it starts out with type `Image?`:

```kotlin
val img = reader.acquireLatestImage() // this is of type "Image?"

if (img == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!")
    return
}
// now img is smart-cast to the type Image (non-nullable)
```

> Is it possible to create extension for that?

You won't be able to encapsulate the non-local return inside an extension function, but you could create an extension function for the logging, and then use a plain elvis operator:

```kotlin
fun YourReader.acquireLatestImageOrLog(): Image? {
    val img = acquireLatestImage()
    if (img == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image is null")
    }
    return img
}

val img = reader.acquireLatestImageOrLog() ?: return
```

You could even go more general:

```kotlin
fun <T> T?.orLog(message: String): T? {
    if (this == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, message)
    }
    return this
}

val img = reader.acquireLatestImage().orLog("Image is null!") ?: return
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example using `run`:

```
val img: Image = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: run {
    Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!")
    // You can place also more code in here -->
    // ...
    // <--
    return
}
```

Or if you simply want it in oneliner, you can place ; after Log.d(...):

```
val img: Image = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: run { Log.d(TAG, "Image is null!"); return }
```